# Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator::Emit, call method from third party .net library

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, reflection.emit

I'm trying to create simple .net compiler for educational purposes. After parsing, scanning and building AST I'm generating .net assembly using `Reflection.Emit.ILGenerator`.

Here is my sample code for assembly generation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string moduleName = "Test.exe";

    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(moduleName));
    AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
    ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(moduleName);
    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("Program", TypeAttributes.Public);
    MethodBuilder mainMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "Main", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), System.Type.EmptyTypes);


    ILGenerator il = mainMethod.GetILGenerator();

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Test!");
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(System.Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new System.Type[] { typeof(string) }));
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    typeBuilder.CreateType();
    moduleBuilder.CreateGlobalFunctions();
    assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(mainMethod);
    assemblyBuilder.Save(moduleName);
}
```

Everything works fine, this code generates executable with following class:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test!");
    }
}
```

Next I'm creating simple third party library with single class which builds to ThirdPartyLibrary.dll:

```
using System;

namespace ThirdPartyLibrary
{
    public class MyPrint
    {
        public static void Print(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Third party prints: " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wish to replace `Console.WriteLine` method call to `MyPrint.Print` method call from my library and get result code something like:

```
using System;
using ThirdPartyLibrary;

public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        MyPrint.Print("Test!");
    }
}
```

As far as I understand I must read my `ThirdPartyLibrary.dll` file, then reflect it somehow to get all types from it and then it will be possible to use `MyPrint` type. Finally I wish to be able to path references as myCompiler.exe arguments like using csc.exe.

**So the questions are:**

- How to do it?
- How all this named? (I can't understand what to google)
- May be I should use some other frameworks, instead of Reflection to do all this?
- Any other suggestions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only change here is the target method:

```
var targetMethod = Assembly.LoadFrom("ThirdPartyLibrary.dll")
    .GetType("ThirdPartyLibrary.MyPrint")
    .GetMethod("Print", new [] {typeof(string)});
...
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Test!");
il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, targetMethod);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

So instead of using `Console.WriteLine`, we call `MyPrint.Print`.

- How to do it? A: like the above
- How all this named? A: IL-generation, meta-programming, reflection
- May be I should use some other frameworks, instead of Reflection to do all this? A: reflection covers most scenarios; I use `IKVM.Reflection.dll` in a few places, because it allows me to do cross-framework targeting, but you probably don't need that. What you *might* find handy is [Sigil](http://nuget.org/packages/Sigil/), which takes away a lot of the pain of IL-generation (unbalanced stacks, etc) by giving you sane error reports at the time you generate (rather than when you execute). Mono.Cecil is also interesting

Comment: It's really cool! I didn't expected that it is so simple to get types from dll. Thanks!